# How to pass one JS var to another JS page

Tags: javascript

I have followed some tutorial on internet and created a little game that works in browsers. It is a canvas game, and with paddle you prevent the ball falling and reflecting it to destroy bricks(I hope you know what I am talking about). I did everything that instructor did in that course but in the end I made some changes and copied that JS code onto another JS page with some changes to it so it passes on "Level 2" when you finish first part of the game.

My problem is that the lives that are implemented in the game aren't passing onto "Level 2", if you know what I mean. You start with 3 lives, for example you lose 1 life, when you finish "Level 1" with 2 lives and continue to "Level 2" you will have 3 lives again, instead of 2. If anyone does understand me, please help. I have probably made this question so awkward and confusing but i had to tell the whole story so you would understand. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far so we can help you.

Comment: try using cookies to save data across subpages

Comment: Look at localStorage. It's an object in browser where you can store your data between redirects/refreshes.

Comment: @PatrickHund
http://prntscr.com/eg8s7q

This is where lives "count". But as i said, i just copy-pasted first JS code that i typed onto new page and just changed bricks and ball.

I am sorry, first time i posted, the screenshot was wrong. This is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to another page, the simply solution is to pass them as query parameters:
https://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-querystring-with-native-javascript/

But in your case I suggest to use sessionstorage or localstorage.
SessionStorage conserve the data until you close the browser: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Whit Localstorage the data persist even if you close the browser:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

If you have complex data to save you can store in a database, see indexeddb:
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API